# how to make a dynamic error message in django form

Tags: django, django-forms

I have this in my forms.py file

```
from django import forms
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User 


class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    password2 = forms.CharField(
    label=_("Confirm password"),
    widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'autocomplete': 'new-password'}),
    strip=False,
    help_text=_("Enter the same password as before, for verification."),
    )
    
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username','email','first_name','last_name','password1','password2']
        error_messages = {
            'username': {
                'unique': 'user already exist',
            },
        }
```

I wnat to dislpay a dynamic error message when a user register with an existing username.
For exmple I my superuser is called 'admin' , if a suer try to rgister with the username 'admin' I want to show him an error message at the end of the form like that:

> `user with the username 'admin' already exist`

instead of the default static message :

> `user already exist`

So how can I do that ??

Comment: Use Crispy Forms. Learn more about it here: https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
   cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
   if User.objects.filter(username = cleaned_data.get('username')).exists():
      raise forms.ValidationError("Username already exists")
```

Define this clean method in form.It will throw error when you call is_valid function on form from views

Read more about it here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/validation/

Comment: you mean to include this function in  the class CreateUserForm , right ?